# loadspeed.js timings : onload, DomContentLoaded or something else?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, headless

Are loadspeed.js timings correct ?

because i have different results between loaspeed.js and developpor toolbar in Chrome.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    t, address;

page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    t = Date.now();
    address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } else {
            t = Date.now() - t;
            console.log('#1 Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
            t = Date.now();
             page.open(address, function (status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('FAIL to load the address');
            } else {
                t = Date.now() - t;
                console.log('#2 Loading time ' + t + ' msec');  
            }
            phantom.exit();
        });
        }
    });
}
```

Running the script give me

```
>phantomjs.exe loadspeed.js http://www.google.com
#1 Loading time 348 msec
#2 Loading time 202 msec
```

With Chrome developper toolbar in private mode, I can see this (nearly the same for two runs)
[image: toolbar result]

As you can see, i don't have the same result (note :each time) and it eventually suggets **that loadspeed mesure DOMContentLoaded Event**.

Is there any 'unconfigured' feature in that script ?

Maybe I am wrong, but simply, how can I mesure page load time ?

Comment: Comparing the values of `Date.now()` is fraught with problems, #1 being the resolution of the JavaScript Date object. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131068/in-javascript-is-there-a-source-for-time-with-a-consistent-resolution-in-millis for more information.

Comment: thanks, but I just want an approximate loading time : it does not really matter if resolution is 50 ms.

Answer (score 2):

Try this right before your call to page.open:

```
page.onInitialized = function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.addEventListener('load', function() {
            t = Date.now() - t;
            console.log('#1 Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
        }, false);
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but you can't add load on document. you have to call window.addEventListener